# How can this js be decoded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how this jQuery file is encoded, and how can I decode this?

```
(function(a){a["\x66\x6E"]["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74"]=function(c,b,d){return this["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var f=this["\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64"],e,g,h=[];if(f){do{if(f["\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x54\x79\x70\x65"]===3){e=f["\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x56\x61\x6C\x75\x65"];g=e["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"](c,b);if(g!==e){if(!d&&/</["\x74\x65\x73\x74"](g)){a(f)["\x62\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65"](g);h["\x70\x75\x73\x68"](f)}else{f["\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x56\x61\x6C\x75\x65"]=g}}}}while(f=f["\x6E\x65\x78\x74\x53\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67"])}h["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]&&a(h)["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]()})}})(jQuery);$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){$("\x70\x2E\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var a=$(this)["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]();var b=$(this)["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x74\x72\x61\x6E");$("\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x2A")["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74"](a,b)})});$("\x23\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var a=$(this)["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]();$["\x61\x6A\x61\x78"]({url:"\x2F\x66\x65\x65\x64\x73\x2F\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x2F\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x2F\x2D\x2F"+a+"\x3F\x61\x6C\x74\x3D\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x2D\x69\x6E\x2D\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x26\x6D\x61\x78\x2D\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74\x73\x3D\x33",type:"\x67\x65\x74",dataType:"\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x70",success:function(k){var h="";var m="\x3C\x75\x6C\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x6E\x61\x76\x22\x3E";for(var b=0;b<k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"]["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];b++){for(var l=0;l<k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"][b]["\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B"]["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];l++){if(k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"][b]["\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B"][l]["\x72\x65\x6C"]=="\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65"){h=k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"][b]["\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B"][l]["\x68\x72\x65\x66"];break}}var c=k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"][b]["\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65"]["\x24\x74"];var p=k["\x66\x65\x65\x64"]["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79"][b]["\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74"]["\x24\x74"];var j=$("\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x3E")["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"](p);var d=j["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x69\x6D\x67\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x73\x72\x63");var g="\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x6E\x61\x76\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22"+h+"\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x3A\x75\x72\x6C\x28"+d+"\x29\x20\x6E\x6F\x2D\x72\x65\x70\x65\x61\x74\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x3A\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x22\x2F\x3E";m+="\x3C\x6C\x69\x3E"+g+"\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x6E\x61\x76\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x65\x6E\x74\x22\x3E\x3C\x68\x33\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x6E\x61\x76\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22"+h+"\x22\x3E"+c+"\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x68\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E"}m+="\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E";$("\x23\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73")["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"](m);$("\x23\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73")["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x54\x6F"]("\x23\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72")}})});window["\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6E\x61\x76"]=function(){var a=function(m,x){function b(c){var d;if(!c){c=window["\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74"]}if(c["\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74"]){d=c["\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74"]}else{if(c["\x73\x72\x63\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]){d=c["\x73\x72\x63\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]}}if(d["\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x54\x79\x70\x65"]===3){d=d["\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65"]}if(d["\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65"]){window["\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E"]["\x68\x72\x65\x66"]=d["\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65"]}}function z(c){var d=c["\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]["\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65"]();return d==="\x75\x6C"||d==="\x6F\x6C"}function w(c){for(var d=1;document["\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64"]("\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6E\x61\x76"+d);d++){}return c?"\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6E\x61\x76"+d:"\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6E\x61\x76"+(d-1)}function k(p){g++;var o=p["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"]["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"],r="",u="",f=g-1;if(!o){return}if(f){while(f--){u+=C}u+="\x20"}for(var i=0;i<o;i++){var E=p["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"][i]["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"][0];if(typeof E!=="\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64"){var s=E["\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x54\x65\x78\x74"]||E["\x74\x65\x78\x74\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74"];var h="";if(q){h=E["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]["\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68"](q)!==-1||E["\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65"]["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]["\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68"](q)!==-1?j:""}if(A&&!h){h=E["\x68\x72\x65\x66"]===document["\x55\x52\x4C"]?j:""}r+="\x3C\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x3D\x22"+E["\x68\x72\x65\x66"]+"\x22\x20"+h+"\x3E"+u+s+"\x3C\x2F\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3E";if(v){var d=p["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"][i]["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"][1];if(d&&z(d)){r+=k(d)}}}}if(g===1&&y){r="\x3C\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x3D\x22\x22\x3E"+y+"\x3C\x2F\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3E"+r}if(g===1){r="\x3C\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6E\x61\x76\x22\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22"+w(true)+"\x22\x3E"+r+"\x3C\x2F\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x3E"}g--;return r}m=document["\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64"](m);if(!m){return}if(!z(m)){return}if(!("\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x41\x64\x6A\x61\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x48\x54\x4D\x4C" in window["\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]["\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"])){return}document["\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]+="\x20\x6A\x73";var B=x||{},q=B["\x61\x63\x74\x69\x76\x65\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73"]||"\x61\x63\x74\x69\x76\x65",A=typeof B["\x61\x75\x74\x6F\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74"]==="\x62\x6F\x6F\x6C\x65\x61\x6E"?B["\x61\x75\x74\x6F\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74"]:true,v=typeof B["\x6E\x65\x73\x74\x65\x64"]==="\x62\x6F\x6F\x6C\x65\x61\x6E"?B["\x6E\x65\x73\x74\x65\x64"]:true,C=B["\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x6E\x74"]||"\u2190",y=B["\x6C\x61\x62\x65\x6C"]||"\x2D\x20\u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0626\u0645\u0629\x20\x2D",g=0,j="\x20\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x20";m["\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x41\x64\x6A\x61\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x48\x54\x4D\x4C"]("\x61\x66\x74\x65\x72\x65\x6E\x64",k(m));var D=document["\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64"](w());if(D["\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72"]){D["\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72"]("\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65",b)}if(D["\x61\x74\x74\x61\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74"]){D["\x61\x74\x74\x61\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74"]("\x6F\x6E\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65",b)}return D};return function(c,b){a(c,b)}}();$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){selectnav("\x6E\x61\x76")});(function(a){var c=a(window);var b=c["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]();c["\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65"](function(){b=c["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]()});a["\x66\x6E"]["\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6C\x6C\x61\x78"]=function(d,k,e){function n(){var f=c["\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70"]();m["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var o=a(this);var i=o["\x6F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74"]()["\x74\x6F\x70"];var p=j(o);if(i+p<f||i>f+b){return}m["\x63\x73\x73"]("\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x50\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E",d+"\x20"+Math["\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64"]((g-f)*k)+"\x70\x78")})}var m=a(this);var j;var g;var h=0;m["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){g=m["\x6F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74"]()["\x74\x6F\x70"]});if(e){j=function(f){return f["\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"](true)}}else{j=function(f){return f["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]()}}if(arguments["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]<1||d===null){d="\x35\x30\x25"}if(arguments["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]<2||k===null){k=0.1}if(arguments["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]<3||e===null){e=true}c["\x62\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C",n)["\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65"](n);n()}})(jQuery);$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){if(window["\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E"]["\x68\x72\x65\x66"]["\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66"]("\x6D\x6F\x64\x6F\x75\x6E\x74\x69\x2D\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74")<0){$("\x23\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x2C\x23\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x2C\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x2C\x23\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72")["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]()}});$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){(function(a){var c=a("\x61\x2E\x6E\x65\x77\x65\x72\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B");var b=a("\x61\x2E\x6F\x6C\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B");a["\x67\x65\x74"](c["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66"),function(d){c["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]("\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x74\x69\x74\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72\x2D\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x3A\x75\x72\x6C\x28"+a(d)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x69\x6D\x67\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x73\x72\x63")+"\x29\x20\x6E\x6F\x2D\x72\x65\x70\x65\x61\x74\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x3A\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E"+a(d)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65")["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]()+"\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x66\x61\x20\x66\x61\x2D\x63\x68\x65\x76\x72\x6F\x6E\x2D\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E")},"\x68\x74\x6D\x6C");a["\x67\x65\x74"](b["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66"),function(d){b["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]("\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x74\x69\x74\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x66\x61\x20\x66\x61\x2D\x63\x68\x65\x76\x72\x6F\x6E\x2D\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E"+a(d)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65")["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]()+"\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72\x2D\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x3A\x75\x72\x6C\x28"+a(d)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x69\x6D\x67\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x73\x72\x63")+"\x29\x20\x6E\x6F\x2D\x72\x65\x70\x65\x61\x74\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x3A\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E")},"\x68\x74\x6D\x6C")})(jQuery)});(function(j){function g(a){j["\x67\x65\x74\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74"]("\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F"+a+"\x2E\x64\x69\x73\x71\x75\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x5F\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x2E\x6A\x73")}function B(){if(m){return}m=true;if(!z){k["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]("\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\u0644\u0627\x20\u064A\u0648\u062C\u062F\x20\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0632\u064A\u062F\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E");return}k["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x61")["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]();k["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x69\x6D\x67")["\x73\x68\x6F\x77"]();j["\x61\x6A\x61\x78"](z,{dataType:"\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"})["\x64\x6F\x6E\x65"](function(f){var h=j("\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E")["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](f["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"](d,""));var i=h["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x61\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72\x2D\x6F\x6C\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B");if(i){z=i["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66")}else{z="";k["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]()}var e=h["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"](y)["\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E"]();j(y)["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](e);var a=function(c){j("\x2E\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x73\x6E\x69\x70\x70\x65\x74")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){c=j["\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64"]({length:350,ellipsis:"\x20\x5B\x2E\x2E\x2E\x5D"},c);var o=j(this);var p=o["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]();var l=p["\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67"](0,c["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"])+c["\x65\x6C\x6C\x69\x70\x73\x69\x73"];o["\x74\x65\x78\x74"](l);o["\x63\x73\x73"]("\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x61\x75\x74\x6F")})};a();$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){$("\x70\x2E\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var c=$(this)["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]();var l=$(this)["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x74\x72\x61\x6E");$("\x23\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x20\x2A")["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74"](c,l)})});if(window["\x5F\x67\x61\x71"]){window["\x5F\x67\x61\x71"]["\x70\x75\x73\x68"](["\x5F\x74\x72\x61\x63\x6B\x50\x61\x67\x65\x76\x69\x65\x77",z])}if(window["\x67\x61\x70\x69"]&&window["\x67\x61\x70\x69"]["\x70\x6C\x75\x73\x6F\x6E\x65"]&&window["\x67\x61\x70\x69"]["\x70\x6C\x75\x73\x6F\x6E\x65"]["\x67\x6F"]){window["\x67\x61\x70\x69"]["\x70\x6C\x75\x73\x6F\x6E\x65"]["\x67\x6F"]()}if(window["\x64\x69\x73\x71\x75\x73\x5F\x73\x68\x6F\x72\x74\x6E\x61\x6D\x65"]){g(window["\x64\x69\x73\x71\x75\x73\x5F\x73\x68\x6F\x72\x74\x6E\x61\x6D\x65"])}if(window["\x46\x42"]&&window["\x46\x42"]["\x58\x46\x42\x4D\x4C"]&&window["\x46\x42"]["\x58\x46\x42\x4D\x4C"]["\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65"]){window["\x46\x42"]["\x58\x46\x42\x4D\x4C"]["\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65"]()}if(window["\x74\x77\x74\x74\x72"]&&window["\x74\x77\x74\x74\x72"]["\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x73"]&&window["\x74\x77\x74\x74\x72"]["\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x73"]["\x6C\x6F\x61\x64"]){window["\x74\x77\x74\x74\x72"]["\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x73"]["\x6C\x6F\x61\x64"]()}k["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x69\x6D\x67")["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]();k["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x61")["\x73\x68\x6F\x77"]();m=false})}function b(){return Math["\x6D\x61\x78"](A["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"](),w["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"](),document["\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]["\x63\x6C\x69\x65\x6E\x74\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"])}function x(){var a=b();var c=A["\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70"]()+A["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]();if(a-c<50){B()}}function q(){if(_WidgetManager._GetAllData()["\x62\x6C\x6F\x67"]["\x70\x61\x67\x65\x54\x79\x70\x65"]=="\x69\x74\x65\x6D"){return}z=j("\x61\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72\x2D\x6F\x6C\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66");if(!z){return}var a=j("\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3A\x3B\x22\x3E\u062A\u062D\u0645\u064A\u0644\x20\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0632\u064A\u062F\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E");a["\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"](B);var c=j("\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22"+v+"\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x3A\x20\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x3B\x22\x3E");A["\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C"](x);k=j("\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x6D\x6F\x72\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E");k["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](a);k["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](c);k["\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65"](j("\x23\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72"));j("\x23\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65\x72")["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]()}var v="\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x34\x2E\x62\x70\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x2D\x4C\x58\x75\x4A\x36\x31\x4A\x32\x63\x4B\x63\x2F\x56\x41\x61\x48\x51\x72\x65\x68\x4F\x5A\x49\x2F\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x45\x70\x73\x2F\x2D\x4D\x52\x70\x4D\x48\x6C\x71\x36\x57\x34\x2F\x73\x31\x36\x30\x30\x2F\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x67\x69\x66";var z="";var k=null;var y="\x64\x69\x76\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73";var m=false;var A=j(window);var w=j(document);var d=/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;j(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](q)})(jQuery);$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){var a=$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65");var c=$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x6D\x65\x74\x61");var d=$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x23\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x20\x2E\x63\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x20\x2E\x70\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64");$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x23\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x20\x23\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72")["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]();d["\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](a);d["\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64"](c);$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x69\x6D\x67\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x2D\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64")["\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74"]("\x61")["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]();$("\x2E\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x20\x69\x6D\x67\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x2D\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64")["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]();var b=function(f){$("\x2E\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x20\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x73\x6E\x69\x70\x70\x65\x74")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){f=$["\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64"]({length:350,ellipsis:"\x20\x5B\x2E\x2E\x2E\x5D"},f);var g=$(this);var e=g["\x74\x65\x78\x74"]();var h=e["\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67"](0,f["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"])+f["\x65\x6C\x6C\x69\x70\x73\x69\x73"];g["\x74\x65\x78\x74"](h);g["\x63\x73\x73"]("\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x61\x75\x74\x6F")})};b();$("\x23\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72")["\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6C\x6C\x61\x78"]("\x35\x30\x25",0.2)});$(window)["\x62\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C",function(){var a=$(this)["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]();$("\x2E\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var c=0.2*$(this)["\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"]();var b=c-a+$(this)["\x6F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74"]()["\x74\x6F\x70"];var d=$(document)["\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70"]();if(d>b){$(this)["\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73"]("\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65")}else{$(this)["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73"]("\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x2D\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65")}})});$(document)["\x6F\x6E"]("\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x2E\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75",function(){$(this)["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]();$("\x2E\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75")["\x73\x68\x6F\x77"]();$("\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x65\x63")["\x73\x68\x6F\x77"]()});$(document)["\x6F\x6E"]("\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x2E\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75",function(){$(this)["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]();$("\x2E\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75")["\x73\x68\x6F\x77"]();$("\x2E\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x65\x63")["\x68\x69\x64\x65"]()});$("\x23\x4C\x69\x6E\x6B\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x31\x30\x30")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var a="\x3C\x75\x6C\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x27\x6E\x61\x76\x27\x3E\x3C\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x75\x6C\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x27\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x27\x3E";$("\x23\x4C\x69\x6E\x6B\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x31\x30\x30\x20\x6C\x69")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var c=$(this)["\x74\x65\x78\x74"](),b=c["\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72"](0,1),d=c["\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72"](1);"\x5F"==b?(b=$(this)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x61")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66"),a+="\x3C\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22"+b+"\x22\x3E"+d+"\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E"):(b=$(this)["\x66\x69\x6E\x64"]("\x61")["\x61\x74\x74\x72"]("\x68\x72\x65\x66"),a+="\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x2D\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22"+b+"\x22\x3E"+c+"\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x75\x6C\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x27\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x27\x3E")});a+="\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x75\x6C\x3E";$(this)["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"](a);$("\x23\x4C\x69\x6E\x6B\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x31\x30\x30\x20\x75\x6C")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var b=$(this);if(b["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]()["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"](/\s| /g,"")["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]==0){b["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]()}});$("\x23\x4C\x69\x6E\x6B\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x31\x30\x30\x20\x6C\x69")["\x65\x61\x63\x68"](function(){var b=$(this);if(b["\x68\x74\x6D\x6C"]()["\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"](/\s| /g,"")["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"]==0){b["\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"]()}})});
```

Comment: try hex to ascii converter `\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74` = `replaceText` - http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ with the right options.

Comment: i used it but i get wrong result

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ejf03HwS as @FelixKling suggested use jsbeautifier.org and click the option "unescape printable characters".